# administration menu for custom module does not appear

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to make my own module. I implemented hook_menu and hook_form and I wanted to test it, but the administration page for it does not exists. I am just learning to work with drupal. Could anyone help me please?

Code for testmod.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function testmod_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/content/testmod'] = array(
    'title' => 'Testmod',
    'description' => 'Configuration for testmod module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('testmod_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

}
function testmod_form($form,$form_state) {
$form['testmod'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Test value'),
'#description' => t('Enter the test value here'),
'#size' => '100',
'#default value' => variable_get('testmod'),
);
return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

I can't acces this form I have created. When I enter mypage.com/admin/config/content/testmod I will get to admin/config/content

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the `hook_menu()` code. It might be related to the actual path (maybe the `content` path is already pointing to somewhere else and considering `testmod` as a parameter).

Did you try with a different path, such as `admin/config/testmod`?